How to create a routinue to almost 9 yo
My kid is going to be 9 yo in 2 months, Lately I had cut cable tv to cut his tv and got him bicycle, he plays well outside but he is having hard time understanding how to set boundries. We talked about how to do study, games and then outdoor but if we don't stop him, it is playing all day or tv. he has 0 interest in studying or gaining knowledge, I am very worried.
Now I have noticed that he is skipping brushing or washing face, we tried to see if he notices and do it himself, but either he skip with a guilt look or lie.
We are worried and I do not know what to do?

First of all, no need to worry as this sounds like typical behavior of a nine year old.  Who wouldn't want to play and delay inconvenient tasks?  As he matures he will be self-motivated for learning and hygiene.
In the meantime, you can help him by setting up a chart with daily responsibilities and privileges.  Each item on the chart can have a number of points that he either earns or spends with bonus points earned for completing all tasks.
The main thing is not to cram in too many responsibilities, just the bare minimum to start with.  For example, 20 minutes of learning a day, teeth brushing, making the bed.  Let him taste success and see how easy it is to complete the daily tasks.  As for privileges, you can have mundane privileges, like 30 minutes of computer games, as well as racking up points to save for something bigger like an expensive toy or trip.  Let him suggest things that he is excited about.

I have noticed my toxic behaviour into telling him to-do something and something else like robot, I am trying to stop it because I been raised like that so I am on autopilot, I have seen improvement in my son activities since I laid back, but I also seen he totally forgot abt stuff e.g. brushing teeth at night time, and if I ask him daily and 98% he has not done it , I feel bad. what to do?

Totally understandable that you'd naturally do what you grew up with, and awesome that you want to give him a better experience.
Personally, I read to my son every night after he brushes teeth.  He looks forward to hearing the next chapter of the mystery and I tell him that the earlier he is ready the more time we have to read.  He is a big reader himself but he also enjoys being read to.
Have you tried a chart?  It can be helpful with building a habit.
